# z-index bad behaviour over some HTML elements

Tags: css, tooltip

I've seen this behavior for years. Checkboxes and radios buttons can not be covered by DIV elements. No matter what z-index use.Is there some solution?

Besides, I am using simpletip (can't use qtip). If you know about another jquery tooltip ready to use that work around this... I have my wallet open. THX

[image]

Comment: I've never seen that problem with check boxes and radio buttons. IE6 does have that problem with select elements, but no current browsers do. Can you show a concrete example?

Comment: Really never seen? :o developing in FF3.6/linux. Users list is created with js. I would like put some code but how do I in this little box??? May i put like an answer???

Comment: FF most certainly doesn't have this problem, so you must be doing something wrong. You could post an URL to a sample document, or if that's not possible build a test case for example with http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: [online sample](http://nomikos.info/private/wp/options-general.php.html) This is a sample of a WP plugin that I develop. It's a dummy page, so no AJAX nor more pages available (its a "save page as" dump). But CSS/HTML can easily be investigated with Firebug. THANKS A LOT IN ADVANCE... o/\o The tooltip is triggered with a click on username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, now we can work.

First off: This probably has nothing to do with your problem, but it can lead to other problems: Your HTML is riddled with errors:

http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fnomikos.info%2Fprivate%2Fwp%2Foptions-general.php.html

Most importantly a `span` may not contain a block element such as a `div`. Most of the errors is because you are using HTML syntax instead of XHTML syntax. It maybe easier just to use a HTML DOCTYPE, than fixing all the XHTML errors.

---

Your actual problem is that `z-index` only applies to elements that are positioned (absolute, relative, fixed) and since your "tooltip" isn't `z-index` has no effect.

You'll need to explain what you want it to do. Until then I can just give general suggestions:

You could make sure that the "tooltip" doesn't become wider than the surrounding `span`. Currently it's 300px wide and since the `span`s are flexible it spills out, when the `span`s become too small.

Or you give the "tooltip" `position: absolute` and smaller `top` and `left` values (BTW the current `top` and `left` values are currently useless, because they also only apply to positioned elements) and it's parent `span` `position: relative`.

Comment: I wanted to answer several days ago. Indeed CSS can be enough hard for a non designer. Finally I used jquery: dialog. Thank you very much for your enlightened response.